# Why is this simple multithreaded program freezing in eclipse - mingw32/gdb?

Tags: c, multithreading, gcc, gdb, mingw

The program below keeps hanging/freezing in GDB 7.4 (MinGW32, Eclipse, Windows) absolutely randomly, estimating about every 5 or 6 runs. It is most easily found by mashing the debug button in eclipse and then checking the debug instances that haven't terminated. You can of course do the same thing by running it like a normal person and likely will get the same result quite soon.

The sample never freezes when not attached to GDB. Ever. I also could not expose the same issue under VC++ Express (it was a different sample but really just the same idea).

It hangs mostly around thread creation, thread deletion, and program termination. Also worth of note is that even though main returns -1 as exit code, when attached to GDB whenever the program doesn't freeze it exits with code 0.

Another interesting fact - when I uncomment the "Sleep(1)" call it stops hanging 80% of the time. When it does freeze however, it freezes after it prints "Return -1\n".
All other terminations continue to return 0 (except when ran w/o gdb).

Without further ado, the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <process.h>

void __cdecl callback(void *arg)
{
    int count = 0;

    while(count < 10)
    {
        printf("Thread 2(%i): looping %i\n", (int)arg, count);
        count++;
    }

    printf("Ending thread...\n");
    _endthread();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Mingw32 on windows w/ eclipse - fix console output not showing up until the app terminates
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
    setvbuf(stderr, NULL, _IONBF, 0);

    bool runMain = true;

    int runCount = 0;

    while(runMain == true)
    {
        if(runCount == 5)
        {
            printf("Thread starting... ");
            int result = _beginthread(callback, 0, (void*)5);
//          Sleep(1);

            if(result == 0)
                printf("[FAILURE]\n");
            else
                printf("[SUCCESS]\n");
        }

        printf("Thread 1: %i\n", runCount);
        runCount++;

        if(runCount == 20)
            runMain = false;
    }

    printf("Return -1\n");
    return -1;
}
```

What do you think is causing this, and more importantly - how do I fix it?

Comment: I'm surprised it does anything.  main() creates 20 threads and exits, terminating the process, probably before the other threads do anything at all.  Is printf() thread-safe? Does exiting main() close the standard in/out?

Comment: @MartinJames thank you for taking a look but you are incorrect. Only a single thread gets created - when runCount hits 5. And that thread has to print to console 10 times, in the time that the main thread has to execute 15 calls to print to console. I played with these variables to no avail, and this is the super simplified version of what I am having a problem with. I broke it down to the smallest code that causes issues. Release mode runs without issues, both threads execute and main one doesn't yield (printf calls are not interleaved).

Comment: Can someone please at least test it? And why was Martin's comment upvoted by 1? He is totally off point...

Comment: Can you try adding something to the end of main() so that the program will not exit? Even doing something as simple as requesting input will achieve this. You're arguing above that the main program could not have exited before the threads did their work -- but let's make sure that's the case.

Comment: @BSchlinker thank you for looking into this. Pausing the program at the end to let the threads finish is not really a problem. The problem is the rather random but consistent hanging when debugging with GDB. It would hang at different times - sometimes on thread start, sometimes at the end of the program. But please note that this is the SIMPLEST version of my problem - my real app doesn't stop it keeps looping and the same symptoms arise.

Comment: @BSchlinker also, part of the problem is that the program does not terminate when it hangs - where in any scenario the program should end execution and return -1.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are too many variables here -- can you perhaps try just debugging it with GDB? I've seen eclipse struggle handling threads / processes before, so it would be nice to determine if the problem is with Eclipse, or GDB..

Comment: Sorry for the delay - yes, I tried debugging in GDB via command line but the results are the same - consistent hanging. I have been using VC++ for the past few weeks and it's a tough transition. Have you tried running the same sample through GDB (and/or eclipse)? I'm incredibly curious if its just me...

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution. There was a bug in GDB [#17247](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=17247) related.

Sending a SIGCONT signal to gdb or to your application makes it work again.

Try run this command next time:

```
killall -s SIGCONT <gdb | your application process name>
```

or

```
kill -18 <gdb pid|application pid>
```

Comment: Good work finding that issue report, but "There is no solution" is unnecessarily bleak.  You've already presented one alternative that changes the hang into a pause.  Since it appears that the issue has been patched in gdb, there are also the alternatives of updating gdb (to at least v7.8), or rebuilding it from appropriately patched source.